# MySQL: no database selected error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

hi i have an sql error says: no database selected this is my KK.php file:

```
$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "MyDB";
$server = "localhost";

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['input1']);

$sql="INSERT INTO demo (message)
VALUES ('$message')";

if (!mysqli_query($link,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
 }
echo "1 record added";

 mysqli_close($link);
 ?>
```

my database is "MyDB", and my demo.php file:

```
<form action="KK.php" method="post" />
<p>Message: <input type="text" name="input1" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

so what is the problem?, how do i select database?

Comment: You have no mysqli_connect statement before mysqli_connect_errno(). Thus you have not selected a database to work with.

Comment: Where's the code where you use `$database`?

Comment: You need to connect to Mysql followed by selecting a DB which is missing in the code http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment above here is the code you are missing.

```
$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "MyDB";
$server = "localhost";

// This
$link = mysqli_connect($server,$user_name,$password,$database); // This
// This

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you forgetting to call the mysqli_connect to get your connection?

ie:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call `mysqli_connect`

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```